# Call a dictionary recursively to find the last value

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I call a dictionary recursively to find the last value, assuming dictionaries may have different depths?

```py
a = {
    'b': {
        'c':'d'
    }
}

m = {
    'b': {
        'c':{
            'd':'e'
        }
    }
}
```

It's just two examples, I'm trying to get the last value, no matter how deep it's located.

The function doesn't work. How should I pass the final value when it get to the string type?

```py
def get_value(x):
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        return get_value(x)
    else:
        return x.get(list(x.keys())[0])
```

Expected outputs are:

```py
get_value(a) == 'd'
get_value(m) == 'e'
```

Comment: What does "last" value mean here? You didn't say what's your examples' output should be, and why.

Comment: You're calling `get_value(x)`, with exactly the same value of `x` that it was called with - that's an infinite recursion, you never actually go any deeper into the structure.  You need to grab the value from the current level (much as you're currently doing in the last line, and then either recurse or return based on whether *that* was a dict.

Comment: It seems that you expect a dict inside both arms of the if

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the desired output. simply want the last value that isn't a dictionary.

Comment: @jasonharper That did the trick! thanks, `return get_value(x.get(list(x.keys())[0]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
a = {
    'b': {
        'c':'d'
    }
}

m = {
    'b': {
        'c':{
            'd':'e'
        }
    }
}

def get_value(x):
    if not isinstance(x, dict):
        return x
    else:
        return get_value(x[list(x.keys())[0]])
        
print (get_value(a))
print (get_value(m))
```

Output

```
d
e
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_value(x):
    for key in x.keys():
        if isinstance(x[key], dict):
            return get_value(x[key])
        else:
            return x.get(list(x.keys())[0])
```

The key had to be passed when recursive function was called again.

Comment: How does the else statement work here? we only reach the else if x is not a dict, but in the else methods like get and keys are called like x was a dict, but we only get to this code when its not a dict

Comment: We get to the else when the keys of x are not a dict, and only x is a dict, i.e., the deepest nested dictionary. It would not have its key as a dict. The if statement checks in the key of x is a dict or not.

Comment: A yes i see, i was thinking you were just testing x, but i see now how this works.